# Android: How to change the custom color on circular progress bar

Tags: java, android, xml

I cannot figure out how to change the default color of my circular progress bar.  I've tried changing the startColor and endcolor attributes under my gradient tag in the below xml file title circular_progress_view.xml, which is a florescent green color, but the default color of magenta is still showing up.  Please see both my layout xml file (main.xml) and circular_progress_view.xml file below

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlaHeaderProgress"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <ProgressBar
            android:indeterminate="true"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_view">
        </ProgressBar>
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_weight="1">

    </ListView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

circular_progress_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:fromDegrees="90"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="360">

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="7.0">

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false"
            android:startColor="#00FF00"
            android:endColor="#00FF00"/>

    </shape>



</rotate>
```

Answer (score 2):

I do it like this and works pretty fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toDegrees="1080" >

    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="12"
        android:useLevel="false" >

        <size
            android:height="76dp"
            android:width="76dp" />

        <gradient
            android:angle="0"
            android:endColor="@color/progress_bar_color"
            android:startColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:type="sweep"
            android:useLevel="false" />

    </shape>
</rotate>
```

And add this to res/values/colors.xml

```
<color name="progress_bar_color">#00ff00</color>
```

And I add ProgressBar like this (note *android:indeterminateDrawable*):

```
<ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_bar"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLargeInverse" />
```